# SonarQube guide for customize rules

Tags: java, sonarqube

I've been working with SonarQube for just a little I have downloaded the project from the https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101 page, I jumped to create my own rules, but I still lack a lot more knowledge by how customizing them, I don't know how to visit the nodes and changing them depending on the element found on the syntax, the SonarQube page doesn't explain more than the custom exercise, is there a specific guide for this?

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101 exercise

Comment: im able to surf to certain parts of the sentece depending on their sintax token type, but i cannot get all the tokens from a sentence sometimes .  how would you figure out this thi is the line ive been trying to read public void getElements() {
  List<WebElement> webElementList = driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//a"));
  if (webElementList.size() < 0) {
  }
 }     with the following code im able to get parts of the "driver."  sequence but i need all the tokens and with visible methods its impossible to get there

Comment: @Override
 public List<Kind> nodesToVisit() {
  return ImmutableList.of(Kind.METHOD);
 }

Comment: @Override
 public void visitNode(Tree tree) {
  MethodTree method = (MethodTree) tree;
  List<StatementTree> statements = method.block().body();
  // System.out.println(statements.size());
  for (StatementTree statement : statements) {

Answer (score 1):

This is done with [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), it's implemented with [Visitor Pattern](https://github.com/iluwatar/java-design-patterns/tree/master/visitor).

The easiest way is to check examples provided by SonarSource: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples

Some examples of AST can be found at [Java Parser book](https://leanpub.com/javaparservisited)

I have done some examples for old version 5.2, you can check them at: https://github.com/devwebcl/sonarqube-plugins-java-5.2